# issues creating img dynamically

Tags: javascript

I do not understand what's going on when it comes to creating an img dynamically. This is the code:

```
const pics = document.querySelector('.gridPics');

eventosListener();

function eventosListener() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        jsonFile();
    });
}
```

I get the pics from a json file. It works well.

```
function jsonFile () {
    fetch('js/fotos.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        showPics(data);
    })
    .catch(function () {
        this.dataError = true;
    })
}
```

Function that must create pictures dinamically

```
function showPics(x) {

    x.forEach(element => {
       
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('grid-item');

        const imagen = document.createElement('img');
        imagen.setAttribute("src", element.name);
        imagen.setAttribute("alt", element.desc);
        imagen.setAttribute("width", '90%');
    

        div.appendChild(imagen);
        pics.appendChild(div);

    });  
}
```

HTML file

```
<section class="fotos">
     <div class="gridPics"></div>
</section>
```

For a while I believed that imgs paths were wrong, but I added a img like this but it does no work either

```
imagen.src = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/300.jpg?hmac=kssNLkcAZTJQKpPCSrGodykV8A6CStZxL7dHvtsVUD0';
```

Json File

```
[{
  "name" : "./../assets/1.jpeg",
  "desc": "imagen1"
  },...
}]
```

The estructure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGOsm.jpg)

I do not have any error in the console but I can not see anything.

Comment: can you confirm that all those functions actually run? have you checked that the request is being made and the forEach in `showPics` is creating all those elements and adding them? sprinkle some console.log's into your code to see what's happening

Comment: If this is your entire code then you missed the part where you actually add these nodes to the DOM.

Comment: @TheWhiteFang no, they are there towards the bottom of `showPics`

Comment: I wrote this console.log(x) in showPics () and I'm able to see the entire json printed. But when I do inside forEach, just one result appears

Comment: So yes,thats exactly the issue my answer solves

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your issue is that the data is not coming in as JSON as you're loading it from a plain text file, you can solve this by ensuring they are using `JSON.parse`.

The below works (ignoring me having to mock out loading the data) just adding `showPics(JSON.parse(data));`

```js
const jsonData = "[{\"desc\":\"imagen1\",\"name\":\"https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/300.jpg?hmac=kssNLkcAZTJQKpPCSrGodykV8A6CStZxL7dHvtsVUD0\" }]";
const fetch = () => Promise.resolve({ok:true, json:() => Promise.resolve( jsonData)});

const pics = document.querySelector('.gridPics');

eventosListener();

function eventosListener() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        jsonFile();
    });
}

function jsonFile () {
    fetch('js/fotos.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        showPics(JSON.parse(data));
    })
    .catch(function () {
        this.dataError = true;
    })
}

function showPics(x) {

    x.forEach(element => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('grid-item');

        const imagen = document.createElement('img');
        imagen.setAttribute("src", element.name);
        imagen.setAttribute("alt", element.desc);
        imagen.setAttribute("width", '90%');
    

        div.appendChild(imagen);
        pics.appendChild(div);

    });  
}
```

```html
<section class="fotos">
     <div class="gridPics"></div>
</section>
```